# Unable to resolve host while cloning on codeberg

Tags: networking, ssh, powershell, dns, git

I am using codeberg for repository management. on my windows PowerShell if I type
git clone git@codeberg.org:codageaider/repotest.git I get the following error:
`ssh: could not resolve hostname codeberg.org Name or service not known`
Not sure why it's unable to resolve the hostname. It could be because it's
restricted by my company. I am unable to ping it too. So I found out the IP
address of codeberg.org which is `193.26.156.135` by doing a ping from a different
machine. and used the command `git clone git@193.26.156.135:codageaider/repotest.git`   which resulted in the error: ssh: connect to host  port 22: connection timed out fatal: could not read from the remote repository...
What could be the reason for this? Although I am able to access the website by going to [www.codeberg.org](http://www.codeberg.org)  Is there a way I could clone the repository on my local system

Comment: Probably the server does not accept connections from the outside world. We have no way to troubleshoot this because we don't have SSH access to that server. Try increasing the SSH debug level to see what exactly it's doing when you connect.

Comment: You can use https without auth using - https://codeberg.org/codageaider/repotest.git  but it does not exist anymore. If you want to use SSH, you have to add a key to your account, see docs here: https://docs.codeberg.org/git/clone-commit-via-cli/